# Converting json file to json object jumbles up the order of objects

Tags: c++, json, ifstream, nlohmann-json

I am trying to parse a json file into a json object using nlohmann json library.

This is the json file:

```
{
    "n":1,
    "data":
    {
        "name":"Chrome",
        "description":"Browse the internet.",
        "isEnabled":true
    }
}
```

This is my code:

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
    ifstream f("/Users/callum/sfucourses/cmpt373/test/example2.json");
    json data = json::parse(f);
    cout << data << endl;
}
```

If I don't do the parse and just do `cout << f.rdbuf()` I get correct output:

```
./interpret
/Users/callum/sfucourses/cmpt373/build
{
    "n":1,
    "data":
    {
        "name":"Chrome",
        "description":"Browse the internet.",
        "isEnabled":true
    }
}
```

but if I do the parse and print out the json object 'data',then "n":1 and "name":"Chrome" is placed at the end instead of the beginning:

```
./interpret
{"data":{"description":"Browse the internet.","isEnabled":true,"name":"Chrome"},"n":1}
```

How do I get it to print in the correct order?

Comment: That's not an ordered part of JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is normally not ordered, but the library provides `nlohmann::ordered_json` that keeps the insertion order:

```cpp
auto data = nlohmann::ordered_json::parse(f);
```

Parsing the file like above and printing it like you do produces this output:

```
{"n":1,"data":{"name":"Chrome","description":"Browse the internet.","isEnabled":true}}
```